# How to reference the same column multiple times with UPDATE -- SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database which includes recipes for specific items. I'd like to create an update statement which updates all item costs based on the costs of the ingredients in their recipe. The problem I believe I am dealing with is that the value 'cost' for both the ingredients and the items for which they are used are located in the same table. I have managed to write a statement which updates the cost for only ONE item, but I can't seem to make this work for ALL items that have a recipe. Attached is the functional statement for ONE item and the statement I tried to compose for ALL items.

This is the statement which returns the correct values, but only applies to ONE specific item number.

```
UPDATE inventory
SET inventory.cost = (SELECT SUM(inventory_ingredients.quantity * inventory.cost)
                      FROM inventory_ingredients, inventory
                      WHERE inventory.itemnum = inventory_ingredients.ingredient
                        AND inventory_ingredients.itemnum = 'BeesKnees1200'
                      GROUP BY inventory_ingredients.itemnum)
WHERE inventory.itemnum = 'BeesKnees1200'
```

and this is the statement I was trying to compose which would update all `Inventory.Cost` with that SUM

```
UPDATE inventory 
SET inventory.cost = (SELECT SUM(inventory_ingredients.quantity * inventory.cost)
                      FROM inventory_ingredients, inventory
                      WHERE inventory.itemnum = inventory_ingredients.ingredient
                      GROUP BY inventory_ingredients.itemnum)
WHERE inventory.itemnum = Inventory_ingredients.itemnum
```

In this scenario, I get a "could not be bound" on inventory_ingredients.itemnum

I think the problem here is that I'm referencing the same column twice, but I'm not sure how to correct it. Any ideas would be really appreciated.

The attached image shows relevant columns for the tables Inventory and Inventory_Ingredients respectively.

Comment: You need to use a CTE there

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I'm really appreciative of the advice. I literally just started learning SQL with no formal education on the subject, so I love tips from pros; however, the link there doesn't seem to want to open. Any ideas where else I could see what you're referencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you change your query to

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(TRY_CAST(II.quantity AS INT), 1) * I.cost) * 1.0000 S,
       II.itemnum
FROM inventory_ingredients II JOIN inventory I ON I.itemnum = II.ingredient
GROUP BY II.itemnum
)
UPDATE inventory 
SET inventory.cost = CTE.S
FROM inventory JOIN CTE ON inventory.itemnum = CTE.itemnum;
```

Comment: Before I try this, I'm worried about executing an update without a WHERE. Is that being replaced with the JOIN here?

Comment: This portion of the query returns the correct cost (yay!)           [SELECT SUM(inventory_ingredients.quantity * inventory.cost) S, Inventory_ingredients.itemnum
FROM inventory_ingredients JOIN inventory ON Inventory.itemnum = Inventory_Ingredients.ingredient
GROUP BY Inventory_Ingredients.itemnum]        But there's something in that bottom JOIN isn't quite working. It updates all the appropriate fields, but the value it's inputting is incorrect.

Comment: @RedDevil Can't see your data, What's wrong with the bottom JOIN?

Comment: Let me take another look at it @Sami, just a sec

Comment: Correction: So the issue is actually in that some quantities are not an integer value. I've found that the updated cost that it's returning assumes a inventory_ingredients.quanity of 1. And, thank you, by the way, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Then you can use `TRY_CAST()` and `ISNULL()` too for that. @RedDevil please check my updates and [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks @Sami, I'll try that

Comment: So I've cast the SUM as decimal, Try_cast doesn't seem to be a built in function in sql server 2012, [SELECT cast(SUM(cast(inventory_ingredients.quantity as decimal(10,4)) * cast(inventory.cost as decimal(10,4))) as decimal (10,4)), Inventory_ingredients.itemnum
FROM inventory_ingredients JOIN inventory ON Inventory.itemnum = Inventory_Ingredients.ingredient
GROUP BY Inventory_Ingredients.itemnum] and It's still returning the same values. still assuming a value of 1 for inventory_ingredients.quantity

Comment: @RedDevil Are you using [SQL Server 2012](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? if not what version?

Comment: I am. SQL Server Mgmt Studio 2012

Comment: forgive me, I've figured it out, the function works perfectly, I just had one item common across all recipes that had the cost listed incorrectly. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code and let me know if it works for you:

```
UPDATE inventory 
    SET inventory.cost = (SELECT SUM(inventory_ingredients.quantity*inventory.cost)
    FROM inventory_ingredients II, inventory I
    WHERE I.itemnum=II.ingredient and i.itemnum = inventory.itemnum 
    GROUP BY II.itemnum)
```

Comment: Without any where condition on the UPDATE clause, I'd advise not trying this....unless you have it wrapped in a transaction with a rollback.

Comment: @Ehsan, in your AND, is that meant to be "inventory.itemnum=inventory.itemnum"?

Comment: No, Inventory is for update level, but i is for inner join inventory. This way, query checks item numbers automatically.

Comment: Outer inventory that we are building is being built based on group by. The inner inventory, i, is the original inventory table.